# Is bumping a question OK?

Tags: discussion, editing

Is it OK to bump a question that received not enough attention (tumbleweed candidate) to the top using an edit?

If so under which circumstances?

Comment: I have not found anything related to this here on meta, maybe the question could exclude the assumption of 'not enough attention' to more generally discuss this topic. (If you think that would be better just edit it out)

Comment: See: [How do I get attention for old, unanswered questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Bumping questions, in the sense of pushing them to the top of the *active* list by editing them, is always encouraged. **As long as the edit in itself is valid!**

Editing a question solely for the purpose of *bumping* it, without providing further information or otherwise improving the question, is **strongly discouraged**.

### What if a question can't be improved, but should still be bumped?

This is exactly what bounties are intended for. *How* bounties work is outlined in detail in the FAQ, in the section [What if I don’t get a good answer?](https://superuser.com/faq#bounty).

### I have no reputation to give, but this question is really, really good!

First of all, nobody is stopping **you** from promoting the question. Feel free to share it on your favorite social network or let a friend have a look at it.

That being said, you can also join us in [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) and discuss the question. Maybe someone else has an idea on how to improve it. Maybe someone even knows the solution or likes the question so much that he/she bounties it.

Lastly, questions automatically get bumped by [Community](https://superuser.com/users/-1/community) if they're inactive for a while.

Comment: Community only bumps questions that are considered unanswered (no positive score answers).

Comment: So, summarising the above: "Don't bump. Instead, expend lots and lots of effort to achieve about the same thing."

Comment: @SteveBennett: This whole topic is about the respect you show other members of the community. Everybody's question is the *most important one* and **has** to be at the top, so everybody must see it immediately when they visit the site. But that's just not how the site works. Everybody gets their share of attention. If you want to *get* more out of the site, you also have to *put* more into it. So, yeah, it may result in "the same thing" for the person that asked the question. But it's not only about the single person on this site.

Comment: Bumping has been around for probably decades now. Yes, there's an etiquette.

Comment: @SteveBennett Bumping on forums has been around a long time and yes there is an etiquette to it but this is not a forum, it is a Q&A site and we have a different etiquette. Not all forums appreciate bumps in the first place anyway.