# What do you do if you want to ask a question, but someone already asked it, and there wasn't a decent answer response?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

The example I've come from is this:

[Merging IMAP account into gmail](https://superuser.com/questions/326595/merging-imap-account-into-gmail)

I have already typed out a better-worded question on the same topic and will probably get fresh, excellent up-to-date answers.

I'd like to post it. But will I get marked down due to it being 'dupe'?

What do I do?

Thanks

Comment: Please also see: [Is bumping a question OK?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5485/is-bumping-a-question-ok)

Answer (score 6):

If you want to get up-to-date answers for an old question, you can **place a bounty** on that question.

See: [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

You can enter a message asking users to provide new answers with current information. The question will then appear in the "Featured" tab on the main site and is likely to be seen by more users.

This is especially useful if the old question isn't sufficiently answered — although in this case it appears to be, so you might want to explain why you'd need to get more answers or what information the current answers are lacking.

Comment: Thanks. I've realised that I'm after a different (and more specific) solution than that existing question (or that answer) covers, so I can go ahead with my new question then, and reference it.

Answer (score 2):

Editing the original question to make it better (expanding, clarifying, etc., without changing it's intent) is another good way to get it more attention, and possibly more answers.

Answer (score 2):

If your question really is better or different, just ask it.  You can reference the older question while explaining why yours is different/better.  If you can make a good case, you'll likely be golden.

You've already written up a new question?  What's the worst that can happen :)

Comment: What's the worst that can happen?  Your question gets closed as a dupe and the one you reference get's closed as off-topic.  (I've seen it done.)

Comment: I think the worst that could happen is your question gets down-voted several times **and** closed as a duplicate.